# Как сделать так чтобы один ноут имитировал мышь на другом через USB?

Tags: delphi

Возникла следующая необходимость: два ноутбука соеденены одним проводом через USB-порт. Как сделать, так чтобы один ноут имитировал МЫШЬ, а другой определял его как МЫШЬ?

И как реализовать програмно эту имитацию?

Comment: Вы хотите возить ноутом по столу вместо мышки?

Comment: уточните пожалуйста каким именно образом вы собираетесь подключать ПК т.к. это довольно таки важная "мелочь"

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю что к ноуту который будет мышью надо прикрепить GPS навигатор что бы определять
его перемещение по столу....

Comment: Вот тут, боюсь, длины кабеля не хватит (даже если найти стол подходящего размера).

Answer (score 0):

Перечитал вопрос, понял, что не так понял. Действительно, вы хотите по столу водить ноутом вместо мышки? 0_о

Ну, а если все же это вариант с одной мышкой на две машины, то вот:

Насколько знаю, такое возможно, если один из ноутов - Apple-овский. Лично мне не приходит на ум ничего другого, как на хосте (ноут, к которому физически подключена мышка) запустить программу, которая будет считывать координаты мыши (её Вы напишете сами), скажем, каждые 100мс и передавать их программе клиенту, которая будет запущена на втором ноуте, она же будет управлять перемещением курсора. Как-то так. Но это лишь идея, реализовать придется Вам. Теоретически, такая система будет работать, практически, я с таким не сталкивался, поэтому гарантии нет.

Comment: Необходимо именно управление через USB, т.е. первый компьютер воспринимал второй как реальное устройство - мышь, потому как
детектирует любое програмное нажатие (событие).

Comment: Да возить ноутом по столу вместо мышки

Comment: честно говоря, мне в таком случае не ясен даже сам процесс. в смысле, не понимаю, откуда будут браться данные о перемещении девайса по поверхности столе, датчиков-то нет по идее.

Comment: Используйте немного скотча и ненужную мышку. Никакого доп. ПО.

Comment: за бутылочку пифка и фотосессию сего чуда помогу просверлить ваш ноут так чтоб воткнуть тудым мышку(полностью спрятать в корпусе), и подпаять к разьему пациента провод от мыфки))))) пациенты естесно ваши))))) работоспособность пациента в первоначальном направлении не гарантирую может стать не ноутбукой а обычной мышэй в оч неудобном корпусе)))

Answer (score 0):

Это невозможно, почитайте специфику работы юсб...

Comment: Ошибаетесь, это возможно. Используют "крещеный" кабель (его можно даже готовый найти) и специфические драйвера. Так можно даже IP гонять. Но, судя по вопросу, автор к подобному моделированию грызуна не готов.